# Calling unknown method: doublesecretagency\googlemaps\models\Visitor::zip() Craft CMS

Tags: html, css

Estoy cambiando Smart Map a Google Maps en Craft CMS pero este error aparece:

```
Calling unknown method: doublesecretagency\googlemaps\models\Visitor::zip()
```

Este es el código:

```
{% set paramZip = craft.app.request.get('zip', googleMaps.visitor.zip) %}
```

`googlMaps` --> antes `craft.smartMap`
`zip` --> antes `zipCode`
`visitor` está igual

Comment: Estás en la versión hispana, traduce la pregunta al español por favor :D

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a esta pregunta es que .zip no es una propiedad real para .visitor actualmente en Google Maps para CraftCMS, por el contrario se puede usar `googleMaps.visitor.raw.zip` ya que el .zip sí está contenido en el array .raw. La razón de no ser una propiedad es "probablemente porque sería tremendamente inconsistente y casi siempre incorrecto". Una buena sintaxis podría ser:

```
{% set paramZip = craft.app.request.get('zip') ?? googleMaps.visitor.raw.zip ?? null %}
```

Espero que pueda ayudarle a alguien y a propósito, existe una nueva versión del mismo plugin para CraftCMS donde se arreglan algunos bugs que encontré.